# In USA, is it expected to thank your management or HR for hiring you?

Tags: professionalism

(This question is not about a thank you note sent after an interview but after the new position is accepted and confirmed.)

Years ago when I worked in an office in Philadelphia (PA), I was talking to my manager in his office when a young male colleague, whom I knew had recently been moved to a permanent role, brought a six-pack of beer to the manager.

Nothing much was said, except that the manager thanked him, but I thought perhaps that was because the colleague had gotten the permanent role.

That was my first job in USA and since that time I have worked in a few different countries as a software consultant. Consequently I now feel like my understanding of any unwritten rules may be a bit out of whack.

So, take for example a software developer who is working on a contract-to-hire position in some large enterprise somewhere in USA.

The individual is offered a salaried position and accepts it.

Are there any cultural expectations of thanking the management for hiring them?

(Footnote: the colleague who has hired in that past experience in Philadelphia was, I think, an administrative assistant. Not sure if this has much bearing however.)

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Are you asking about thank you gifts or just the words?

Comment: "Looking forward to starting ..." would be an alternative and is more common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the USA is not the strictest of cultures when it comes to politeness and etiquette, showing it is never wrong.  I should point out that individual states, and even **REGIONS** of individual states can have their own sub-cultures.  So there is no specific answer for this other than "depends on the location".

A simple "thank you" is always appreciated, and universally accepted.

Spoken is always good.  A written thank-you in the form of an email would also be fine.  I would avoid gifts or hand-written notes or cards as that may seem a bit odd, but that's the worst it will be seen.  You won't be thought of badly if you present a small gift or card, but they may look at you funny when receiving it.

Comment: would the down-voters please explain what's wrong with this advice?

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any cultural expectations of thanking the management for
>   hiring them?

In the USA, based on my experience as a life long resident, when something is offered to you typically a "Thank You" is appropriate and depending on the personality of the person offering, its expected.

This would include an opportunity of employment IMHO.  And why not, they are  **two short and simple words** to speak.  Why risk offending anyone, its easy to display a bit of gratitude?

To recap, if you are offered anything from a glass of wine to a job opportunity in the USA, it is wise to say "**Thank you**",  even if you refuse what is being offered.  You can never go wrong using this approach.

If you're offered a job, just in case this is what your after, there is *no need to purchase a thank you gift*.  A simple **spoken thank you** will do.